# XML XPATH Query sibling value with multiple sibling attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML, I am wanting to build an XPath query to get me the text of the Body node which contains the HTML

```
<documents>
 <document>
  <items>
   <item name='Form'>
    Procedure
   </item>
   <item name='Body'>
    <![CDATA[<p>arbitrary html</p>]]>
   </item>
  </items>
 </document>
 <document>
  <items>
   <item name='Form'>
    Process
   </item>
   <item name='Body'>
    Some arbitrary value
   </item>
  </items>
 </document>
</documents>
```

I am able to get close, I am just missing something. (this may not the best way to get there, but its the only way I have been able to get close)

```
//document/items/item[@name='Form'][text()='Procedure']/../item[@name='Body']
```

Results in the CDATA wrapped content, I am lost as to how select the inner text.

```
//document/items/item[@name='Form'][text()='Procedure']/../item[@name='Body']/text()
```

Is yielding an empty string

Comment: More background, I have a XSL and using a value-of query to try and inject the results from the query into my page.  It appears that there is a bigger issue here than simply my query and the structure of my XML.

If I modify the XML and only have the single node I am looking for and do a query for //item[@name='Body']/text() its still an empty string

Comment: using disable-output-escaping enables this to work on IE, but not in Firefox, any idea on how this can work in Firefox as well as IE?

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPATH to get your expected results:-

```
//document[items/item[@name='Form']/text()='Procedure']/items/item[@name='Body']/text()
```

### Result:

```
<p>arbitrary html</p>
```

### UPDATED:

I got the actual issue on your XML.

The value of form node contains spaces, which is causing issue.

To solve this issue, use this new XPATH with `normalize-space()`

```
//document[normalize-space(items/item[@name='Form']/text())='Procedure']/items/item[@name='Body']/text()
```

### Result:

```
<p>arbitrary html</p>
```

Comment: Well I like this query more, I am still getting an empty string when I do the /text().